# Updating the nested attributes of a form before saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I have a map.rb that accepts nested attributes for detail, which has a embeds_one relation

In details there is a rules array, I would like the user to be able to input a textarea full of rules and those get separated into the array by newline's. I tried before_create callbacks n both map.rb and detail.rb but they weren't fired properly which cause a Mongo field error. If you know how to get before_create working in this situation here's what I tried:

```
class Map
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :uploader, type: String
  field :upload_date, type: Date

  embeds_many :teams
  embeds_one :detail

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :detail, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :teams, :allow_destroy => true

  before_validation :fix_rules

  def fix_rules
    detail = self.detail
    detail.rules = detail.rules.gsub("\r", "").split("\n")
  end
end
```

and then tried putting the before_validation in detail.rb

```
class Detail
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :version, type: String
  field :objective, type: String
  field :proto, type: String, :default => "1.3.3"
  field :rules, type: Array, :default => []

  embeds_many :contributors

  embedded_in :map
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contributors, :allow_destroy => true
  before_validation :fix_rules

  def fix_rules
    self.rules = self.rules.gsub("\r", "").split("\n")
  end
end
```

but neither seemed to work, so I tried to stick the field updating in the controller, but that is not working either

```
def create
  @submission = Map.new(map_params)
  details = params[:map][:detail_attributes]
  if details[:rules].kind_of?(String)
    details[:rules] = details[:rules].gsub("\r", "").split("\n")
  end

  if @submission.save
    flash.now[:notice] = 'Thanks for the map submission!'
    redirect_to maps_path
  else
    flash.now[:error] = 'Submission failed, try again?'
    render :new
  end
end
```

If you know of a way to fix any of my three attempts that would be awesome, since I would prefore a before callback method.

Here's the console output of the action:

```
Started POST "/maps" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-19 00:45:20 -0500
Processing by MapsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     "authenticity_token"=>"L+EkbFCx6WEiLTSxGpAZuqwdrhLlGAtwaHOqFx7+AHc=", "map"=>    {"detail_attributes"=>{"name"=>"", "proto"=>"1.3.3", "version"=>"", "objective"=>"",    "rules"=>"Gi\r\ns\r\ns\r\ns\r\ns\r\ns", "contributors_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"",    "contribution"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "teams_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"", "color"=>"", "size"=>"", "max_overfill"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms
```

Comment: can you put the params that you are receiving in create action.

Comment: updated question with console output of action

Comment: I guess, in your controller you have assigned all the params after which you are replacing and splitting the string. You must either first replace and split and then create the Map object so it holds the right values or with your existing code you must reassign the replaced values to the rule field. Hope it helps.